# What method do I use to close a modal in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, ionic2, angular2-services

I can open the modal just fine, but it isn't clear to me from any documentation whether there is a straight forward method to close the modal. I thought there was a dismiss method already on ModalController, but the log errors say otherwise. The ionic documentation isn't helpful enough. Does anyone know where else to point me?

```
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

 }

 Dismiss() {

   this.modalCtrl.dismiss();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from the doc.

> The modal can later be closed or "dismissed" by using the
>   **ViewController's** dismiss method.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Answer (score 1):

Solution is attached below:

```
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {

 }

 Dismiss() {
   this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
 }
```